# how to align tabs (whitespaces) on github when using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, whitespace

within eclipse when using inline comments `//` i do, for my sake, align all the comments at the same position using tabulator, i.e:

```
$this->site=new openRTB_site($mixed->site);                     //See Site Object       
$this->device=new openRTB_device($mixed->device);               //See Device Object
```

but when i commit to github and see the file there, some of my lines got broken like:

```
$this->site=new openRTB_site($mixed->site);                     //See Site Object       
$this->device=new openRTB_device($mixed->device);           //See Device Object
```

how can i handle this in comfort way? (not using external white space parser)

example of my broken file here: https://github.com/ulkas/openRTBphp4/blob/master/openRTBphp4.php

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that GitHub shows each `TAB` as **8** spaces :)

I can only think in two solutions:

- change your editor to show each `TAB` as 8 spaces
- change your editor to use spaces instead of `TAB`

Comment: I'm seeing this problem even on a line that has no tabs at all.

Answer (score 0):

A must have Eclipse tool for dealing with these type of whitespace issues is [AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/).  Especially the Tabs > Spaces and Spaces > Tab conversion features could be useful for your situation.